# cakephp belongsto custom condition issue

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I’m using cakephp 1.3 with mysql database and engine is MYISAM, I’m getting problem in relationships.  I have two tables name `Organizatio`n and `OrgClasses`, these two are associated with `mbo_studio_id` which is common in both table.

**organization**
`Id(PK)`, `name`, `mbo_studio_id`

**org_classes**
`id(PK)`, `name,date`, `mbo_studio_id`

I’m trying to fetch data on the condition of `mbo_studio_id`, but it adds another condition by primary key of `OrgClasses`.

```
var $belongsTo = array(

    'OrgClass' => array(
        'className' => 'OrgClass',
        'foreignKey' => 'mbo_studio_id',
        'conditions' => array('OrgClass.mbo_studio_id' => 'Organization.mbo_studio_id'),
        'order' => 'OrgClass.date DESC',
        'dependent' => false,
    )
);
```

I get following query

```
SELECT `Organization`.`id`, `Organization`.`name, `Organization`.`mbo_studio_id`, `OrgClass`.` id`,`OrgClass`.`mbo_studio_id`, `OrgClass`.`name`, `OrgClass`.`date`
FROM `organizations` AS `Organization` 
LEFT JOIN `org_classes` AS `OrgClass` ON (`Organization`.`mbo_studio_id` = `OrgClass`.`id` AND `OrgClass`.`mbo_studio_id` = Organization.mbo_studio_id)
```

Here I don’t want **`Organization`.`mbo_studio_id` = `OrgClass`.`id`** condition in query.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then you need to set foreignKey to false:

```
 'foreignKey' => false,
```

This way it will only use your custom conditions.